# Contextual links for programmatically embedded views

Tags: views

When embedding a View programmatically, using views_embed_view, what can I do to have the contextual menu (gear icon) appear over its area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views does this by wrapping the render array output with the views_add_block_contextual_links() function. It checks if the display plugin has contextual links associated with it. If the $display_id is a block then it will have the contextual links.

```
  if ($view = views_get_view($name)) {
    if ($view->access($display_id)) {
      $output = $view->execute_display($display_id);
      // Before returning the block output, convert it to a renderable array
      // with contextual links.
      views_add_block_contextual_links($output, $view, $display_id);
      $view->destroy();
      return $output;
    }
    $view->destroy();
  }
```

You already understand the $name and $display_id. The output from this needs the render() function. You can put this in a function that is called in TEMPLATE_preprocess_node(), for example, and then use `print render($embedded_view)` in the node.tpl.php template.

Comment: Hi Adam S, I can see the `#contextual_links` and `#views_contextual_links_info` key of the `$output` array, but strangely `print render($output);` doesn't display the contextual links. Am I missing something ? Thanks