# How to add programmatically contextual link 'edit' to quiz question?

Tags: 7, quiz, navigation

Since the way to get to a quiz question to edit it is very long, I want add a contextual link to each quiz question.

But somehow I struggle to find a solution. Because it is not a [block](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-7-tip-add-contextual-links-anything) and not a [view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30261/contextual-links-for-programmatically-embedded-views).

I have something like this added to my menu_alter hook:

```
$items['node/%node/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit',
    'page callback' => 'node_page_edit',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'node_access',
    'access arguments' => array('update', 1),
    'weight' => 0,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,
    'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
  );
```

and added `render($title_prefix)` to my template. But somehow it does not work. I know I have to add contextual links to my page at all - but how can I archive this?

Comment: have you turned on Drupal core's Contextual Links module already?

Comment: @longboardnode yes it's tuned on.